# Add a component to controlfx maskerpane

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, controlsfx

I want to be able to customize the content in ControlFx MaskerPane.

I tried using the below code to add a component to it but no luck

```
MaskerPane mp = new Maskerpane();
mp.setProgressNode(new Text("Thank you for Your support"));
mp.setVisible("true");
```

Please how can I achieve this as it will be nice to have more than text and progress indicator in a MaskerPane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in impl.org.controlsfx.skin.MaskerPaneSkin::createProgressIndicator
 there the contents of the progress node are *set* as the graphic of the Progriss-indicator-label not bound to it. as a consequence updating the ProgressNode does nothing.

My workaround is to substitute the Skin:

`masker.setProgressNode(fancyProgessnode);
 masker.setProgressVisible(true);
 masker.setSkin(new MaskerPaneSkin(masker));`